# singleton class shared between app and extension

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

When i add value like reference for `UIViewController` or string Id to singleton class, then try to access them from share extension i could't get this value again 
the share extension create new singleton with null value

How i can make this class and the data inside it shared between main app and extension?

```
class Gateway:NSObject {

    private var id:String? = nil
    private weak var delegate:GatewayDelegate!

    func set(id:String){
        self.id = id
    }

    func set(gatewayDelegate:GatewayDelegate){
        self.delegate = gatewayDelegate
    }

    func dismiss() {
        self.id = nil
        self.delegate = nil
    }


    func append(str:String,_id:String) {

        if let id = self.id ,id == _id ,self.delegate != nil  {            
            self.delegate!.gatewayAppend(str: str)
        }
    }

    static let shared = Gateway()
    private override init() {}
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is unclear. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: i wanna add some item to my view controller from extension

Comment: I don't think a singleton is the solution here since the app and the extension are different processes I guess and then doesn't share memory so they end up with one instance each of the singleton, you need some API or perhaps use UserDefaults to share data

Comment: how can achieve this by userdefault container ,i need to update my viewcontroller directly with new item , so i think if we use userdefault then we need to read the data from this when view will appear again ,this behavior not exactly what i am try to do

Answer (score 10):

An extension is a completely separate process. It runs in its own sandbox and its own memory.  Both your main app and your extension can create an instance of the singleton object, but they will be separate instances. They won't share any data.

To exchange data between your main app and your extension you will need to use an [app group](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_application-groups) with user defaults, the keychain or a file.

Comment: so how i can update my viewcontroller with new val inside my UserDefault before appear ,i tried to use singletone class to pass new val from extension to main app directly and update view with new item before appear from background

Comment: You would need to use something like a shared user defaults suite and have your main app re-read the user defaults value when it returns to the foreground

Comment: You haven't explained clearly what you are trying to do; what are the steps that a user would perform and what you want to happen, but a singleton instance isn't shared between your app and your extension.  Wherever you were trying to access the updated data from the singleton you should be able to read your shared user defaults